# htaccess redirects for old domain to new

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My website is changing domains and I have created a series of 301 redirects in my ".htaccess" file to redirect just over 100 pages which were successful on the old site. There are 100's more but I would rather redirect everything else to a single page on my site informing users of the changes to the website. The old site and new site have different url structures so it's not as simple as re-writing the base domain. I'm also switching the site to entirely secure (https). I've only listed two examples of my redirects below but there are lots more:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^about$ "https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/about\-us" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^another$ "https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/another\-page" [R=301,L]
```

My last redirect is for the base url only (when the customer has a link to the old home page):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^$ ""https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/"" [R=301,L]
```

I want a final redirect (i.e. if a specific redirect is not already listed in my 100 current re-directs for other pages of the old domain) to ensure anything else all goes to a specific page informing the customer of the site change (for example: https://www.newdomain.com/new-site-info).
Would I simply ensure the last redirect in the list is open? Such as include "/?" in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/new\-site\-info" [R=301,L]
```

Would the above rule clash with the base domain rule, or would these rules be best set in a different order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules should be in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/about-us [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^another/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/another-page [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

# catch all rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule . https://www.newdomain.com/new-site-info [R=301,L,NC]
```